# Can I run multiple app in iphone simultaneously

Tags: iphone

I want to run two app simultaneously, I am using jailbroken phone and dont want to upload that app to the app store.

Is there any way so that I can log phone call time, this can only be done if my "logging app" is running in background.

Please suggest me, how can I do this on jailbroken phone.

Some thing like:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms884959.aspx (its for windows)

Comment: Kenny - fixed spelling. Sorry to take away the funny.

Comment: replace said iphone with an Android phone ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to include CoreTelephony, will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Is this actually a programming question, or are you asking for an app that logs call times?

Assuming the former, you would write a iPhone program that hooks into current phone conversations some way (private APIs? Not sure if this is indeed possible, just assuming.) You would then run your app via Backgrounder or some other wrapper that provided an interface for multiple applications to run at the same time. This usually comes at the cost of increase battery life, depending on how much CPU (and maybe memory?) the backgrounded app consumes.

Backgrounder is available via Cydia, I believe.

Comment: Thakns coxymla, I have backgrounder with me. But I have no idea about call AP (its not documented in apple developer site). Please suggest me any private API by which I can access phone call. Thanks you so much